# Why does spark-submit fail with “The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.”?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed Spark in my local machine(Windows). After installation, when I try to type:

> spark-submit C:\Users\Owner\Documents\BigData\try.jar

I am getting the following error:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

[image]

I thought it could be due to spaces in Directory name, so I tried without spaces but I am still getting the same error.

I also checked my JAVA_HOME and tried to modify it without spaces as below

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
>   C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

What could be the reason?

Comment: what happen if you wrap the path with "

Comment: Well, I am not sure but PATH kinda looks correct.

Answer (score -1):

That is a standard error message, probably from `FormatMessage` or internally in Cmd.exe.

`%JAVA_HOME%` is a Java thing, Cmd.exe does not care.

[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-submit.cmd) spark-submit.cmd just does

```
cmd /V /E /C ""%~dp0spark-submit2.cmd" %*"
```

and at some point it ends up in spark-class2.cmd which uses another batch file that requires python. Make sure python is in %path%.

My only suggestion is to sprinkle some `echo`s in those batch files until you find the location where the batch file dies.

Comment: But I am using relative path and I am trying to execute it from the folder where spark-submit.cmd resides.

Comment: Agreed. This is the standard message but what could be the reason behind it. I have all things in place.

Comment: It is probably a issue in the batch file

Comment: It's spark-submit command which I am trying to execute. So I doubt it could be the problem.

Comment: If you look at the right column on this page there are plenty of related (if not duplicate) questions about this exact issue and spark batch file problems.